# Take Photo with Android app inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera

I am developing an android application, and I need to enable it to take photos, I have read many similar questions here and also many links on the web, but it seems there are so many ways to do this, in addition I am writing most part of my codes inside a `Fragment` so none of those links was very helpful for me

This is my code

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 /*
  some codes here
 */  
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new MyFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}

 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}


private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File image = File.createTempFile(
    imageFileName, 
    ".jpg",         
    storageDir     
);
mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
return image;
  }
```

btw I copied and pasted the `onActivityResult` and `createImageFile` codes from this link 
http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

And inside my `MyFragment` class I have

```
    public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_activity, container, false);

       cameraButton = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);

        cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent takePictureIntent = new     Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            }
        });
```

**Question**
Now I have no idea how should I invoke those methods `createImageFile`and `OnActivityResult` from `MyActivity` inside `MyFragment` to get them working together, in other words how to have access to stored image inside fragment.

please also let me know if I have to provide more details about my code

Comment: what methods? you have tried override the 'onActivityResult' in fragment

Comment: Your problem is that you don't handle the result, check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

write this code on MyFragment insted of Activity

Comment: thanks for the answer maybe I was not clear enough I edited the question could you please reas it one more time

Comment: @Siavosh i am not clear with your question i think you access method of Activity from fragment ?

Comment: yes you can modify my question to that maybe I have put so much details to ask that

Answer (score 0):

Add this class to your fragment and let the fragment handle the result.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```